# Rename misspelled [priviliges] meta tag to [privileges]?

Tags: support, retagging, meta

The [priviliges](/questions/tagged/priviliges) tag here on Aviation Meta is misspelled (its subject is questions having to do with privil**e**ges); can we rename the tag to its correct spelling ([privileges](/questions/tagged/privileges))?

Answer (score 5):

Just 4 questions are easy enough to retag and move the excerpt over